# Load XML from Disk in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am using C# test project .I wish to load a Xml which is available inside the project under a folder Dump .  I am able to do

> string path =
>   "C:\APP\FrameworkTest\TestProject\Dump\GetAddressById.xml";

but i don't want to use like this because if the drive changes,my code will fail.

in asp.net we have something like Server.MapPath() . Is there some thing like this ?

Comment: Place your path to the folder in an environment variable and use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var path = Path.Combine(dir, "Dump", "GetAddressById.xml")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway if we speaking about this kind of stuff, what you think which one is better: "Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location" or "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" ?

Comment: I am using a test project .I am getting  the path as C:\Framework\AppFrameworkTest\TestResults\George_Zacharia_WN7-J8BR7BS 2011-06-16 12_31_47\Out\Dump\GetAddressById.xml

Comment: I think `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is right thing as it will be the path where application is installed and where `Dump` folder should be. Now say the app is in directory `C:\MyApps\Test1` and referenced assemblies are in `C:\MyApps\Test1\lib\`. Now if you want path of `Dump` folder from some dll inside `lib` using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`  folder you will get `C:\MyApps\Test\lib\Dump\....` which is obviously wrong. Also you can get permissions/security issue if referencing something from GAC or other shared location.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that folder `Dump` will always be present in the deployement folder of your application then you certainly don't need to hard code full path.

For ASP.net:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/"), "Dump",
                             "GetAddressById.xml");
```

For C#:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Dump", 
                                  "GetAddressById.xml");
```